# how to display the menu?

Tags: python, django-cms

please help show the menu.

there is a menu:

```
structure
    pages
        index
        results
        item
    menu
        about
        tags
        rubrics
        popular
```

I need to print only on the page:

```
about
tags
rubrics
popular
```

my unsuccessful attempts to solve the problem:

```
{% show_menu 1 1 0 100 %}
```

but in this case appears:

```
pages
menu
```

it is not something that requires

Comment: Please share more of your code here. At the moment, it's unclear what you're asking and what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I adminpanel appointed menu id "menu". and use the following placeholder:

```
{% show_menu_below_id "menu" %}
```